# Simple iteration algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, math

If we are given with an array of non-linear equation coefficients and some range, how can we find that equation's root within the range given?

E.g.: the equation is

[image]

So coefficient array will be the array of *a*'s. Let's say the equation is

[image]

Then the coefficient array is `{ 1, -5, -9, 16 }`.

As Google says, first we need to morph function given (the equation actually) to some other function. E.g. if the given equation is `y = f(x)`, we should define other function, `x = g(x)` and then do the algorithm:

```
while (fabs(f(x)) > etha)
  x = g(x);
```

To find out the root.

The question is: how to define that `g(x)` using coefficient array and the range given only?

The problem is: when i define `g(x)` like this

[image]

or

[image]

for the equation given, any start value for `x` will lead me to the second equation's root. And no one of 'em would give me the other two (roots are `{ -2.5, 1.18, 6.05 }` and my code gives `1.18` only).

My code is something like this:

```
float a[] = { 1.f, -5.f, -9.f, 16.f }, etha = 0.001f;

float f(float x)
{
    return (a[0] * x * x * x) + (a[1] * x * x) + (a[2] * x) + a[3];
}

float phi(float x)
{
    return (a[3] * -1.f) / ((a[0] * x * x) + (a[1] * x) + a[2]);
}

float iterationMethod(float a, float b)
{
    float x = (a + b) / 2.f;

    while (fabs(f(x)) > etha)
    {
        x = phi(x);
    }

    return x;
}
```

So, calling the `iterationMethod()` passing ranges `{ -3, 0 }`, `{ 0, 3 }` and `{ 3, 10 }` will provide `1.18` number three times along.

Where am i wrong and how should i act to get it work right?

**UPD1**: i do not need any third-party libraries.

**UPD2**: i need "Simple Iteration" algorithm exactly.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: Very wordy duplicate of [Equation Solvers for C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180327/equation-solvers-for-c)

Comment: Updated the question: only hand-made "simple iteration" method is needed. Without any third-party libraries. Just hand-made small bite of code.

Comment: Numerical algorithms can vary a lot depending on what function you are using. What do you know about your input functions? Are the polynomials? Are they diferentiable? once? twice?

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: ??? the only similarity I see is that both are asking about equations.. :/

Comment: @missingno: maan, he has the coefficients...

Comment: @missingno, read the question carefully: there are equation examples. Yeah, equation is defirentiable. Yeah, it is polynomial. Input function is a function with `x^3` as maximum (sorry, dunno how to say it correctly on English).

Comment: @shybovycha: Sorry all those g(x) got me a little confused. Are you trying to do Newton's method for root finding?

Comment: @missingno, no. It is called "simple iteration". Take a look at http://mpec.sc.mahidol.ac.th/numer/STEP9x.HTM for details on what i mean.

Comment: once you have a root, you can do a polynomial division with `(x-root)`

Comment: The "simple iteration" you describe is not actually a general method but is more of a general describtion of iterative methods. You might want to look at Newton's method. The basic idea is setting up a phi that uses a first order (linear) aproximation of your function to find the next tentative root.

Comment: @missingno, can you put this answer in a more detailed way and as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [link](http://mpec.sc.mahidol.ac.th/numer/STEP9x.HTM) you posted in your comment explains why you can't find all the roots with this algorithm - it only converges to a root if `|phi'(x)| < 1` around the root. That's not the case with any of the roots of your polynomial; for most starting points, the iteration will end up bouncing around the middle root, and eventually get close to it by accident; it will almost certainly never get close enough to the other roots, wherever it starts.

To find all three roots, you need a more stable algorithm such as [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) (which is also described in the [tutorial](http://mpec.sc.mahidol.ac.th/numer/STEP10.HTM) you linked to). This is also an iterative method; you can find a root of `f(x)` using the iteration `x -> x - f(x)/f'(x)`. This is still not guaranteed to converge, but the convergence condition is much more lenient. For your polynomial, it might look a bit like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

float a[] = { 1.f, -5.f, -9.f, 16.f }, etha = 0.001f;

float f(float x)
{
    return (a[0] * x * x * x) + (a[1] * x * x) + (a[2] * x) + a[3];
}

float df(float x)
{
    return (3 * a[0] * x * x) + (2 * a[1] * x) + a[2];
}

float newtonMethod(float a, float b)
{
    float x = (a + b) / 2.f;
    while (fabs(f(x)) > etha)
    {
        x -= f(x)/df(x);
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << newtonMethod(-5,0) << '\n'; // prints -2.2341
    std::cout << newtonMethod(0,5) << '\n';  // prints  1.18367
    std::cout << newtonMethod(5,10) << '\n'; // prints  6.05043
}
```

There are many other algorithms for finding roots; [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) is a good place to start learning.

Answer (score 4):

One of the more traditional root-finding algorithms is [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). The iteration step involves finding the root of the first order approximation of the function

So if we have a function 'f' and are at a point `x0`, the linear fisrt order approximation will be

```
f_(x) = f'(x0)*(x - x0) + f(x0)
```

and the corresponding approximate root `x'` is

```
x' = phi(x0) = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0)
```

(Note that you need to have the derivative function handy but it should be very easy to obtain it for polynomials)

---

The good thing about Newton's method is simple to implement and is often very fast. The bad thing is that sometimes it doesn't behave well: the method fails on points that have `f'(x) = 0` and some inputs in some functions it can diverge (so you need to check for that and restart if needed).